# Android MultiSelectListPreference is crashing

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-multiselectlistpreference

I try to use `MultiSelectListPreference` in my android project.

I defined all settings as you can see:

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
    android:key="key1"
    android:title="title"
    android:dialogTitle="title"
    android:summary="dsfsdfsf"
    android:entries="@array/entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/entryValues"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:defaultValue="@array/defaults"/>
```

In `strings.xml`:

```
 <string-array name="entries">
    <item>Entry1</item>
    <item>Entry2</item>
    <item>Entry3</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="entryValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="defaults" />
```

I get the Error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be
>   cast to java.util.Set
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getStringSet(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:232)

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now. The code is correct. It was the data in the background. 
As soon as i deleted all data of the app including the cache, All works very well.